# Cefsharp CefSettings and RegisterScheme not found

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have install cefsharp via nuget, copied required dlls, added a web view into the form and ran the application and it worked well. However when i try to use Cef initialize Cef to start custom request handling and that stuff, Visual Studio can't find `CefSettings` nor `Cef` classes. I am using the latest CefSharp 1.25.3 for winforms.

Code:

```
var settings = new CefSettings {RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088};
settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
{
    SchemeName = CefSharpSchemeHandlerFactory.SCHEME_NAME,
    SchemeHandlerFactory = new CefSharpSchemeHandlerFactory()
});

if (!Cef.Initialize(settings)) {
    if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("--type=renderer")) {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}

Cef.RegisterJsObject("bound", new BoundObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

If calling Cef.Initialize is throwing exceptions saying that there are references missing, you may have to assure that all the dependencies, especially the unmanaged ones are located in your working directory. A list of the needed resource can be found here in the CefSharp FAQ: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies